# Delete all strings containing x amount of something

Tags: regex, shell, text, sed

I have a rather big text file containing strings that look like this:

`//a/b/ww/d/
 //b/d/we/c/
 //a/b/as/d/e/
 //af/y/x/f/e/
 //b/d/we/c/`

I am trying to remove all the lines that have only 6 forward slashes in them.

The text between the slashes is random and can be longer or shorter.

Desired output:

`//a/b/as/d/e/
 //af/y/x/f/e/`

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a tailor-made job for `awk` to act on count of `NF` (number of fields) deliited by `/`:

```
awk -F/ 'NF != 7' file

//a/b/as/d/e/
//af/y/x/f/e/
```

`NF==7` means there are 6 slashes (delimiter) in a line.

Answer (score 2):

Use grep with the `-v` (inverse match) flag to remove rows matching 6 appearances of `/`. Assuming your file is located @ `/tmp/test.txt`, this command will work:

```
grep -Ev "^[^\/]*(\/[^\/]*){6}$" /tmp/test.txt
```

I just tested it with your example input:

```
$ grep -Ev "^[^\/]*(\/[^\/]*){6}$" /tmp/test.txt
//a/b/as/d/e/
//af/y/x/f/e/
```